How accurate are 'jank' alerts in adroid studio?
I have a simple app which does some not-too-complex calculations in separate threads in a MainViewModel java class, whose methods are called from within a MainActivity.java class which in turn updates a very simple UI with two buttons, two text fields and a text view.
I am getting these warnings of high skipped frames:
2024-04-28 15:32:20.893 20041-20041/com.niff.inout I/Choreographer: Skipped 365 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2024-04-28 15:32:31.805 20041-20041/com.niff.inout I/Choreographer: Skipped 298 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2024-04-28 15:33:25.564 20041-20041/com.niff.inout I/Choreographer: Skipped 2733 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.


I have used the emulator (API level 30) for the most part, but the warnings have also come on my device - on one occasion over 16,000 frames skipped.
They seem to come as the app is loading onto the emulator or device.  I have overriden the MainActivity's 'onResume()' method to read very simple data from a file (again, on a separate thread in MainViewModel.java).
The warnings come randomly and inconsistently - I can go days on end with the numbers of skipped frames below 50, then suddenly they are in the thousands.  But I have never noticed any flickering of the screen on the emulator or device, which I understand is the main symptom of 'jank'.
I get the warnings on both the debug and release versions, in fact the warning of 16,000 was (I think) on the release version on my device.
I don't know how relevant this is, but when I switch between debug and release versions I get an 'IDE error' (Android Studio Chipmunk).
I have tried to follow the advice here https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/jank-detection but do not really understand the instructions for use of the profiler.
I have only 8Mb of RAM on my laptop - is that a factor?
Can forgotten debugging breakpoints in the code affect this issue?
Thanks very much for taking the time to reply!  I have actually written this in Java, not Kotlin, but I think I have pretty much done what you suggest.  I have this in my onCreate method:`
myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    final Observer<String> resObserver = new Observer<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final String result){
            binding.history.setText(result);
        }
    };
    myViewModel.getResult().observe(this, resObserver);

plus every time myViewModel is initialised:
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<String> res = new MutableLiveData<>();
File file;
fric fri;
ArrayList<fric> spends;
StringBuilder sb;
String stats = "";
private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#####0.##");
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0.00);
BigDecimal totals[] = new BigDecimal[12];
boolean isTotal = false;
Month month;
int mois, savedMois;

public MainViewModel() {
    file = new File("data/data/com.niff.inout/files/amounts.dat");
    spends = new ArrayList<fric>();
    month = today.getMonth();
    mois = month.getValue();
}

('fric' is a very simple java class for keeping track of items of expenditure)
plus every time onResume is called I have this method in myViewModel:
protected void readObjects(){
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (file.exists()) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                    Object obj = ois.readObject();
                    spends = (ArrayList<fric>) obj;
                    obj = ois.readObject();
                    totals = (BigDecimal[]) obj;
                    savedMois = ois.readInt();
                    ois.close();
                    fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread myThread = new Thread(runnable);
    myThread.start();
}

I cannot guarantee the quality or accuracy of the code (though it does work!) - I am a complete amateur.  Is it too much going on?  16,000 frames skipped is way more than I have seen on any other posts (and above you can see 2733 skipped).  And I have mainly been using the emulator, though I take on board your comments about devices - my device is a Motorola Moto e30, a very cheap device though entirely adequate for my needs (long time user of Motorola!).

Newer devices might not experience issues, but the older ones definitely will notice.
Best thing to do is to abstract as much work as possible into a coroutine, so it runs asynchronously.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html
Then use LiveData to notify the UI once data is available.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata
Here's an example of a LiveData/Flow implementation with a ViewModel.
So, Let's say you have a simple app that writes notes into Room Storage.
Here's the Dao
@Dao
interface NotesHandler{
    fun getNotes() : Flow<List<Notes>>
}

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor (val myDbContext: RoomDatabase): ViewModel(){

     val notesHandler = myDbContext.getNotesHandler().getNotes().asLiveData()
}

Then in your activity/fragment (onCreate):
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        viewModel.notesHandler.observe(this){
            // my data is process here
            binding.textView.text = it[0].note
        }
    }


Thanks very much for taking to time to answer this.  I have actually used Java to write the app, and I think I have pretty much done what you suggest.  I have this in my onCreate method:

Please mark this as the answer then. Pretty please :)

Sorry, I didn't realise it had saved that comment, I really intended to edit my question which I have done.  Thanks very much again for taking the time to address this!
